# Wordpress global variables?

Tags: metabox, shortcode

I've got page with metabox called "something". It can have two values "value" and "value2".

I'm using a shortcode at this page and want it to display something's value. The problem is I don't know how to access global variable in a shortcode?

Example, I have this in page.php:

```
if($something == "value") {   
     global $one, $two; 
     $one = 120;
     $two = 240;
}
```

Now I want to access these variables in my shortocde (functions.php file), but

```
echo $one; echo $two;
```

Gives no output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta data is save in postmeta table and to get them you can use `get_post_meta($post_id,'meta_key_name',true);`

so in your shortcode function globilaize $post object and get you value like that

```
if($something == "value") {   
     global $post; 
     $one = get_post_meta($post->ID,'value_name'true);
     $two = get_post_meta($post->ID,'value2_name'true);
}
```

Comment: actually in my case I believe I can't do what I want using meta data. I have timthumb generated images and based on site layout I want to change their dimensions. And I'm not able to get given pages layout inside functions.php.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're firing those echos from within a function through page.php, functions wont get anything from those globals because they are set up after functions.php runs.

Try this:

in functions.php:

```
function show_me_that_stuff() {
    global $one, $two;
    echo $one;
    echo $two;
}
```

then in page.php:

```
if($something == "value") {   
     global $one, $two; 
     $one = 120;
     $two = 240;
}
show_me_that_stuff();
```

Now it should output 120240.

Answer (score 0):

Post specific values like you're demonstrated should be post_meta as demonstrated by Bainternet. No question.

However, if it isn't page specific and is truly global, you also have the wp_options table with a specific API for dealing with that.

Comment: Yeah my answer is more of a php explanation rather than a wordpress answer, my bad.